# Is combined Strings of LinkedList of strings palindrom?

Tags: java, c, palindrome, singly-linked-list

Question is: You have Singly linkedlist which contains String[any no of chars] in its node. Now How to find combined String[no need of building string from linkedlist] is palindrome or not ?

Example: ["abc"]-->["d"]-->["ed"]-->["c"]-->["ba"]    --> is valid input linkedList
          combined string would be- abcdedcba

This is what I have thought of:

1.Traverse all list by node and compute combined string length-N.

2.take two pointer point to First Node, P1, P2.

3.advance P1 till reach to string length >=N/2.[we have to remember previous total length] now advance char pointer within node string to point to N/2+2th char[if N is odd] or N/2+1th[if N is even].

4.Start from P2 with char pointer to first char of node string. and perform equal on chars.

5.If P1 reach to end with all char exhausted. then string is palindrome.

but in this approach i'm traversing linkedlist 2.5 times. which will be not good if LinkedList will be huge.

Can anyone suggest better approach.

Comment: This should rather be asked at http://cs.stackexchange.com/ as it is about the optimal algorithmical solution to the very simple problem.

Comment: Why would an even length not be a palindrome? "abba" is a palindrome, isn't it?

Comment: @Durandal I made the same point, but abba is four characters!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch well he writes "2.If length even - not a palindrome.", I stopped reading there ;)

Comment: @Durandal I've edited the question now. What would you say now?

Comment: @neel I would make my life simple by flattening the list into a StringBuilder and work it from there using charAt().

Comment: @Durandal ya I know that solution but that would be not good as of space complexity will be more.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is optimal, you cannot do **anything** with the list faster than O(n) (because the problem requires reading all its elements), and your solution is O(n). Traversing 1.5 times (not 2.5 times - one iteration to the half, and one from the half to begining and from the halt to the end) is also very small constant. If you do not want to rebuild the string I am pretty sure that there is no faster solution (Although your solution consumes N/2 additonal space, but it is unavoidable if you have just one-directional list).

Comment: will my solution still be faster if we have millions of node in linkedList ? Not sure. What is your thought on this?

Comment: it does not matter, you won't get any faster then linear, it is impossible from the theoretical point of view. An milions of nodes (with short words in it) is still under a second.